# How to limit angles of a vector?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I try to write a script that show the sprite that follows by finger. But I need to this sprite can move only on specified distance from the anchor and only between specified angles. Now, I have the next code:

```
public class GunPowerController : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject _fingerprint;
    public Transform _anchor;
    public Gun _gun;
    public float _maxPower = 1f;
    public float _maxAngle = 15f;
    public float _minAngle = 0f;

    private Camera _camera;
    private GameObject _fingerprintInstance;

    void Awake()
    {
        _maxPower = Mathf.Abs(_maxPower);
        _camera = Camera.main;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            var touchWorldPosition = _camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
            var hitInfo = Physics2D.Raycast(touchWorldPosition, Vector2.zero);

            if (hitInfo && hitInfo.transform.gameObject.Equals(gameObject))
            {
                touchWorldPosition.z = transform.position.z;
                _fingerprintInstance = (GameObject)Instantiate(_fingerprint, touchWorldPosition, Quaternion.identity);
            }
        }
        else if (_fingerprintInstance != null)
        {

            if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
            {
                Destroy(_fingerprintInstance);
            }
            else
            {
                var touchWorldPosition = _camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
                Move(touchWorldPosition);
            }
        }
    }

    private void Move(Vector3 target)
    {
        target.z = transform.position.z;
        Vector3 distance = target - _anchor.position;
        Vector3 axis = _anchor.position;
        axis.x = -1f;
        float angle = Vector3.Angle(axis, distance) * Mathf.Sign(distance.y - axis.y);

        if (distance.sqrMagnitude > _maxPower * _maxPower)
        {
            distance.Normalize();
            distance *= _maxPower;
            target = _anchor.position + distance;
        }

        if(_minAngle > angle)
        {
            //Here I need to hold vector rotation while the user doesn't
            //return to the available space between angles.
        }
        else if (_maxAngle < angle)
        {
            //Here I need to hold vector rotation while the user doesn't
            //return to the available space between angles.
        }

        _fingerprintInstance.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(_fingerprintInstance.transform.position, target,
            10f * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

I try to rotate a vector `target` on difference `_min|maxAngle - angle` but it works wrong. How to make it?
The current problem:
[image: Scheme]
P.S. I retried a lot of variants but coldn't make it. If it needs some details, pls, write me I'll post.

Answer (score 1):

Basically rather than trying to figure out the rotational math, I just lerp between the normal (but with the same magnitude as the target vector), treating it as zero rotation, and the over capped vector, and use the amount that the vector has over capped the target angle to determine how far to lerp.

```
public static Vector3 ClampAngle(Vector3 vector, Vector3 normal, float maxAngle, float magnitude = float.NaN)
{
    //Get the angle between the normal and the current vector
    float angle = Vector3.Angle(normal, vector);

    //If the angle isn't greater than max angle, then we don't need to do anything
    if(angle > maxAngle)
    {
        //Avoid sqr root calculation in magnitude if we already know it, otherwise get magnitude from the original vector
        if(float.IsNaN(magnitude))
        {
            magnitude = vector.magnitude;
        }

        //Value becomes the percentage from zero to our overcapped angle, so by lerping to that percentage place we can shift the vector to the max angle
        float value = maxAngle / angle;

        //We use the given normal, times the magnitude of the original line to get our un-rotated positon, we then multiply that by value to apropriatlly
        //shorten the vector based on how long it would have to have been to be a the same position at a different angle.
        //Then we lerp betwen that vector and the original vector to find a vector that has an angle that is not greater than given angle based on the percentage value we got above.
        vector = Vector3.Lerp(normal.normalized * magnitude * value, vector, value);
    }
    
    //Return the vector
    return vector;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Mathf.Clamp` .

Link :https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Clamp.html

Comment: I know how to limit numbers. I don't know how to make it for the vector angle

Comment: The vector length can be changed always.

Comment: Mathf.Clamp(transform.rotation.y, 0, 15);

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about it!

Comment: It doesn't work! As I understood it limits a object rotation but I need to limit a vector rotation. See my picture, please. The fingerprint rotates never, just it moves in the calculated position.